# How do I input ^ instead of ˆ

Tags: macos, keyboard, imac, input-source

In my iMac 21.5-inch computer (OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.1) I have a cordless keyboard.

At the top of the key <kbd>6</kbd> I have <kbd>ˆ</kbd> instead of <kbd>^</kbd>.

This is a problem. I never have needed to use <kbd>ˆ</kbd>, however <kbd>^</kbd> I need to use it very often. For example, formatting formulas at [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) with *MathJax*.

Therefore I need to look it up in the Internet.

Is there a special shortcut for having an input of <kbd>^</kbd>? Or is there a way to change my keyboard inputs?

Comment: Does Shift+6 not bring up `^`?

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry No. It brings me up ˆ. But in the keyboard it has the figure you say.

Comment: That's really weird. What keyboard format do you use?

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry What do you mean? I use [this keyboard](http://i.imgur.com/Gvthacu.png), if it is what you are asking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to go to Keyboard Preferences and add a new keyboard.

Instead of using [*USA International keyboard*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmbSN.png) you will need to use [USA Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1o5e.png).

So from

[image]

Use instead

[image]

1. When you are going to add a Keyboard you select English.
2. At the end of the list you will see both keyboards. Use the one that is not international.

[image]

---

Another option is to put the ˆ and before you press another key, press the space bar.

Comment: As suggested by Pichi Wuana, add the USA Keyboard instead of USA International Keyboard and **don't forget to remove previous one USA International Keyboard**

Answer (score 0):

You can find the combinations to many more symbols by opening "Keyboard Viewer".

The combinations in here should reflect your current keyboard layout as specified under `System Preferences > Keyboard`.

To open Keyboard Viewer, click the menubar keyboard icon (if you don't have it, it's enable it from `System Preferences > Keyboard`) and select "Show Keyboard Viewer". 
[image]

I suggest pressing <kbd>Option</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to modify the keyboard input under Keyboard Viewer.

Comment: 1. I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/bQLnJ0M.png) where you told me to go. 2. [I can't do *replacement of shortcuts* that have less than 2 characters](http://i.imgur.com/C1q0C5T.png).

Comment: For point 1, look under the first tab, last option, for two, good point. I suggest looking at keyboard viewer to identify where `^` actually is. I must've overlooked the two-character minumum

Comment: Oh! I resolved it. It was changing from English International Keyboard to English keyboard. I guess I answer my own question?

Comment: Sure. I just went and looked under "English International - PC" and I understand why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit space bar after you have typed down ˆ and you will turn it into ^.

Comment: This solution is already included in the top answer from 3 years ago.

Answer (score -3):

Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> That's an 'i', not a lowercase L  'l' or '1'. If that doesn't work, switch to a new keyboard.